# How to translate: I will send to Mr/Ms

Tags: english-to-german, preposition, grammatical-case

I would like to write: "Will you get my CV or **should I send it to Ms Smith**?"

In German :

> Ich **soll CV Frau Smith schicken**

or

> Ich soll CV ***zu*** Frau Smith schicken

Comment: Is "_ will you get my CV or i should send it to Ms Smith_" meant to be one sentence that you want to translate, or are these to alternatives?

Comment: @Arsak it is eng version of the sentence

Comment: Ist der Begriff CV im Deutschen schon so stark verbreitet oder sollte man hier in der Übersetzung nicht lieber stattdessen den Begriff Lebenslauf verwenden?

Comment: @mtwde Das hängt von der Branche ab.

Answer (score 1):

Neither. I suggest to write

> Soll ich meinen CV an Sie oder an Frau Smith senden?

Answer (score 1):

Either

> … oder soll ich Frau Smith mein CV schicken?

or

> … oder soll ich mein CV an Frau Smith schicken?

In questions without question words, the conjugated verb is in first position in German.

It's *mein CV*, because the *curriculum vitae* is neutral in German. You can replace it with *es* of course. Or you use *meinen Lebenslauf* and replace it with *ihn*.

And you may use either a dative object *Frau Smith* or a prepositional object *an Frau Smith* but you have to take care about the order of objects.